# Javascript localStorage to avoid a Chart's loss on webpage refresh

Tags: javascript, websocket, charts, javascript-objects

I have a webpage that is presenting chart. I need that when a refresh occurs, the data printed on the web page's chart will not be erased. I looked up and found I should use local storage to not to loose the latest printed data.
When I refresh the webpage, I loose the latest printed Chart's CandleBar.

```js
if(localStorage.getItem("autoSaveStorage")){
        const getAutoSaveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('autoSaveStorage'));
        getAutoSaveData.charts[0].panes[0].sources[0].state.symbol = Datafeed.urlParameter.fullname;
        tvWidget.load(getAutoSaveData);
        console.log(getAutoSaveData);
        tvWidget.load(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('autoSaveStorage')));
        document.getElementById('tradVuTitle').innerHTML =  Datafeed.urlParameter.symbol + " " + localStorage.getItem("lastClosedPrice");
    }



    tvWidget.subscribe("onAutoSaveNeeded", function(res){
        tvWidget.save(function(res){
            localStorage.setItem('autoSaveStorage',JSON.stringify(res));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        });
    });
```

I only need it to be saved upon refresh, is there a way to handle this immediately before the refresh? Or should I continuously update the local storage through each change in my properties and variables?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't impact performance, the safest option is to continuously update, as you are guaranteed to save the data even if the browser crashes, computer dies, etc.

Otherwise, you might be able to make use of the `window.beforeunload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event. This fires before a page reload which would allow you to save before a refresh. If you do something like this, I would still recommend saving from time to time in case the page is closed in some unexpected way.